# debug info could found in libxxx.a, while no info in executable elf file

Tags: debugging, gcc, static, ld

The problem:
mips paltform, gcc, gdb tools.

The project firstly generate many static libraries, then link them to a executable file.

Now we get a core file, use the unstripped version to debug, when I want to use "info locals" to see more info, get the result: "no symbols available"

My research:

I find the debug info in libxxx.a when using "objdump -D -S" to make disassembling.

I use the same command on the final executable file, the same function, could not get the debug info,

I think that is the reason while I get "no symbols available"

I search the makefile:

```
gcc -o xxx -Lxxx -lxxx -lmmm -lnnn, no other options
```

I want to know why I could not get debug info in final elf file.

Comment: bt command get 10 frames, the 10th frame could get debug info, other 9 get no debug info.

Comment: gcc version 4.9.4 (Buildroot 2016.08-rc1)